# Printing deck of cards using classes in python 3

Tags: python, class

I am having an issue with only one card printing when I run my file. It is only printing "Two of Spades". I wish to print the whole deck. I have no problems printing when I do not use classes. But right now I am trying to understand classes. Could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? My code below.....

```
RANKS = {2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven",
         8: "Eight", 9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen",
         13: "King", 14: "Ace"}

SUITS = {1: "Spades", 2: "Clubs", 3: "Diamonds", 4: "Hearts"}
################################################
class Card():
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s of %s" %(self.rank, self.suit)

class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for r in RANKS.values():
            for s in SUITS.values():
                self.cards.append(Card(r, s))

    def __str__(self):
        for i in self.cards:
            return str(i)

deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

Comment: You can only `return` one value from any method, so `__str__` returns only the first card. Also `i` isn't a great name for a card.

Comment: @daniherrera see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/3001761

Answer (score 3):

`return` returns *immediately*. You need to concatenate all individual card strings into a single string, then return *that*.

For example,

```
def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join([str(i) for i in self.cards])
```

Comment: A more compact way to do it: `return ', '.join(map(str, self.cards))`

Comment: `', '.join(str(i) for i in self.cards)`. Why create the `list` at all ? :)

Comment: It's more efficient to create a list with the list comprehension and let `join` iterate over that, than for `join` to iterate over a generator.

Comment: `join` has to make two passes over its input; one to determine the final length of the string so it can allocate enough memory, then again to actually copy each string into that buffer.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that, join with generators will be faster and more memory efficient

Comment: Generators are slower, *because* they are more memory-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

the str function on Deck returns in the first iteration of the loop, thus you only get one card back.

```
def __str__(self):
        cards = ''
        for i in self.cards:
            cards += str(i) + ' '
        return cards.strip()
```

should give a string with all the cards